# Найти угол между тремя точками

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия

Необходимо определить угол точки C относительно двух точек А и В, точки A и B образуют "отрезок", который можно ассоциировать с осью X, так как точка В зависит от точки А, а именно точка В это:

```
B.y = A.y; 
B.x = A.x + A.radius;
```

Угол необходимо определять от 0 до 360 градусов.
Для наглядности рисунок:

[image: Пример точек]
И вторая задача, имея угол, найти точку под тем же углом но на радиусе "обзора".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что значит *угол точки C относительно двух точек А и В*?

А вообще - угол между двумя векторами легко находится с помощью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, как искать скалярное произведение и длины векторов - рассказывать не надо? :)

Судя по рисунку, ваши вектора - AB и AC.

Второй вариант - в вашем варианте он даже проще - посчитать тангенс (точнее, арктангенс) - только (если С/С++) воспользоваться функцией `atan2` - она обрабатывает всевозможные ситуации...

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, я так и думал что можно это решить с помощью векторов, но угол между векторами находится в пределах [0; 180], мне необходимо [0; 360]; Можете посоветовать книги\литературу для изучения тригонометрии? чтобы было понятно и наглядно)

Comment: Ну так смотрите, С ниже AB или выше, только и всего...

Comment: школьный курс геометрии...

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос старый, но я дополню. Посчитать тангенс мало, он не даст определенности от 0 до 360 градусов. Арктангенс даст какой-то угол к которому можно будет добавить ещё 2*pi*k (где k целое число). Посчитайте ещё синус или косинус. Или только синус и косинус.
АВ имеет угол к оси Ох. АС тоже имеет угол. У вас на картинке он измеряется в другую сторону, а не как принято. В любом случае АВ может быть и не на оси. Тогда угол А это угол АС к оси Ох минус угол АВ к оси Ох. И измеряется он против часовой стрелки. Можно узнать его тангенс как тангенс разности углов:

tan (ХАС – ХАВ) = (tan ХАС – tan ХАВ) / (1 + tan ХАС * tan ХАВ)

Так как тангенс это разность координат игрек деленная на разность коодинат икс:

tan ХАС = (y[С] – y[А]) / (x[С] – x[А])

и аналогично с другим тангенсом. Надо вот в таком виде подставить в формулу для разности тангенсов. Потом преобразовать её, чтобы не была она четырёхэтажной. Будет

tan alpha = ((y[С] – y[А]) * (x[В] – x[А]) – (y[В] – y[А]) * (x[С] – x[А])) / ((х[С] – х[А]) * (x[В] – x[А]) + (y[С] – y[А]) * (x[В] – x[А]))

И используя формулы для получения синуса и косинуса через тангенс:

sin alpha = sqrt((tan² alpha) / (1 + tan² alpha))

cos alpha = sqrt(1 / (1 + tan² alpha))

Подставив в них можно получить:

sin alpha = ((y[С] – y[А]) * (x[В] – x[А]) – (y[В] – y[А]) * (x[С] – x[А])) / (sqrt((y[B] – y[А]) * (x[В] – x[А])) * sqrt((y[С] – y[А]) * (x[C] – x[А])))

cos alpha = ((x[С] – x[А]) * (x[В] – x[А]) + (y[В] – y[А]) * (y[С] – y[А])) / (sqrt((y[B] – y[А]) * (x[В] – x[А])) * sqrt((y[С] – y[А]) * (x[C] – x[А])))

Подробнее и нагляднее тут, в учебнике (стр. 51, Зельдович – Математика для начинающих физиков). А я мог накосячить с адаптацией для этого случая да и формулы в книге красивее. Тут смотреть на формулы 1.9.1 и 1.9.2 а и б.

[image: стр. 51, Зельдович – Математика для начинающих физиков]